# LAN settings "Bypass proxy server for local addresses" checks itself

Tags: windows, proxy

The marked checkbox keeps checking itself every now and then. (See the screenshot below.) I have no idea why, but it is really annoying having to uncheck it every time I notice it turned itself back on.

[image]

Does anyone know why it would happen? Any specific program or rules that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as this got little to no response, I decided to fix it myself in an alternative way.

I created a .bat file with this content:

```
REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyOverride /f
```

And then I just created a Scheduled task to run it every time "The workstation is unlocked".